# php structured output result in foreach loop

Tags: php

What i did wrong?

Build array after query:

```
$arr = array();
while($r = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $arr[$r['team1']][$r['stadium']] = array($r['coach'] => $r['age']);
    $arr[$r['team2']][$r['stadium']] = array($r['coach'] => $r['age']);
}
```

Showing data, HOW CAN i Put team 1 and team2? example:

```
<?php foreach($arr as $team => $stadiums): ?>

    <div><?php echo $team;?> AND <?php echo $team;?></div> //----- HERE I NEED PUT TEAM 1 AND TEAM 2

    <?php foreach($stadiums as $stadium => $coaches): ?>

        <?php foreach($coaches as $choach => $ages): ?>

            <?php foreach($stadiums as $stadium): ?>

                <div><?php echo $stadium;?></div>

            <?php endforeach; ?>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

SO hard to understand, how can i write 2 $team in one iteration =)) What i do wrong?

Comment: Also, if you could update your question to post the output of `var_dump($arr)` (before the foreach loop) then that would be helpful.

Comment: `<div>$stadium</div>` is wrong, try   `<div><?php echo $stadium; ?></div>`

Comment: `<div>$team AND $team2</div>`  it should be `<div><?php echo $team;?></div>` because you will not get both indices in same iteration. For each iteration you will get one team

Comment: @Maximus2012 I know about php tags! in one iteration i need write $team1 and $team2

Comment: @Samir I know about php tags! in one iteration i need write $team1 and $team2

Comment: How can i write $team1 and $team2 in one iteration!

Comment: @user3737786  understood but what about `$stadium` in that case? Want to see both `$stadium` in same iteration?

Comment: I think @Samir is correct. You can't do it this way in single iteration. You may have to iterate through `$arr` twice, once to display the team name and 2nd time to display the rest of the information.

Comment: use print_r for any level